# My question over problem building has been put on hold as unclear, is it clearer now?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

[My question on problematization](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/63240/clarifying-where-does-creating-a-philosophical-problem-methodology-come) has been put on hold. I've clarified and added references on problematization, i.e. problem/paradox building. Is it clearer now ?

Answer (score 3):

As a native English speaker the word "problematization" sounds odd. So does "problem building". Rather than define such words find a simpler way to ask the question.

You have also referenced Ghandi, Kierkegaard and Maslow. I would quote something from Kierkegaard (since this is a philosophy site) and ask how Kierkegaard might answer the question which I understand to be whether thoughts about the meaning of life are only relevant to more developed cultures who have the time for such speculations.

When using "first world" you admitted that this sounds "a bit provocative". Don't be provocative. Readers might think you are trying to promote a personal philosophy.

Don't forget that people on these stack exchanges *want* to be able to answer your questions. Give them questions they can answer with minimal input of their own personal opinions.

Comment: For what it's worth, [problematization is a technicalish term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problematization) (in my opinion, very unfortunately).